# Вдруг, откуда ни возьмись

Tags: фразеология

Взошло солнце, и снега **как не бывало**. Здесь пишется НЕ. Вдруг, **откуда ни возьмись**, воробей слетел с куста. Здесь пишется НИ. А почему?

**Вот ответы:**

(1) Откуда я это знаю - не знаю. Просто много читал раньше в том числе и сказки. Вот и запомнил.Мне кажется, что для среднестатистического человека важно правильно писать, а не правила знать.

(2)"Откуда ни возьмись" - устойчивое выражение, под правила не попадает, придется уж запомнить, как есть.

(3) Частица НИ  придает наречию **обобщающий смысл**, усиливая утверждение (не отрицание!), что кто-то или что-то появляется **неизвестно откуда**.

Мне ответы не очень нравятся. Совсем не очевиден обобщающий смысл, усиливающий утверждение.

**И мне хочется задать такие вопросы:** Почему здесь пишется частица НИ? Какое значение (или значения) имеет это  устойчивое выражение? Какой прямой (дословный)  смысл лежит в его основе? Эти значения совпадают?

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Откуда ни возьмись = взявшись ниоткуда.
Комментарий из правил :

> Одноименные частицы не и ни различаются по значению: не —
>   отрицательная, **ни — усилительная**. Поэтому в придаточных
>   уступительных частях предложений **для усиления утвердительного
>   смысла употребляется частица ни** : И во всю ночь безумец бедный, куда
>   стопы ни обращал, за ним повсюду Всадник Медный с тяжелым топотом
>   скакал (П.), а в независимых восклицательных и вопросительных
>   предложениях (при наличии или возможности подстановки
>   усилительных частиц только, уж ) пишется отрицательная частица не :
>   Куда он только не обращался! (частица только усиливает последующее
>   отрицание).

[Gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.58)

Строки из знаменитой песни :

"И в какой стороне я ни буду,
По какой ни пройду я траве,
Друга я никогда не забуду,
Если с ним повстречался в Москве!"

Comment: Грумант (или как Вас там теперь называть), Ваши песни (как всегда) ничего не объясняют. "От Москвы до Бреста на земле нет места, где бы **не** гуляли мы с тобой". И в чем разница Вы никогда не объясните с такими фразами.

Comment: Куда ни обращал -  обращал в любую сторону, во все стороны, в какой стороне я ни буду - в любой стороне, во всех странах. Таким образом, в каждом конкретном случае  (по крайней мере, для каждого местоимения)  требуется собственное толкование.

Comment: Зачем отдельное толкование? Усиление во всех случаях, когда автор текста пишет именно НИ, согласно приведенному правилу.

Answer (score 3):

Vera, здесь не должно быть сомнений. Правила, не сомневаюсь, Вы знаете.
"Не" и "ни" - в своих основных, канонических функциях. Только к фразам присмотреться надо.

**"Как не бывало"**
Смысл тот, что "как будто и **не было**". "Не" - отрицательная. Сравнивается с ситуацией, когда "снега не было". Да, в реальности он был, но отрицание-то относится к той гипотетической ситуации, когда его **не было**.

**"Откуда ни возьмись"**
"Ни" здесь усилительная, не отрицательная, ведь смысл в том, что кто-то или что-то **взялось**. А не "не взялось".

"Ответы", конечно, неправильные. Хотя в (3) некоторый смысл заложен. Вплоть до последней фразы с "неизвестно откуда". Если бы мысль была развита в другую сторону ("взялся *ниоткуда*"), можно было бы счесть даже в чем-то правильным правильным, хотя и неполным.

А откуда этот вопрос - и чьи это ответы?

(+)

Да, насчет "дословного смысла, который в основе". Я, возможно, не совсем понял Ваш вопрос, отвечал как понял. Если разжуете, я попробую и ответы дополнить.

Ну а значения, как Вы понимаете, совсем не совпадают, едва ли не антонимы.

Comment: Ответы взяты из форума "Большой вопрос". Частица НИ, конечно, усилительная, но смысл усилительных конструкций может быть разный, его задают все три слова  (местоимение, частица, глагол). Например, "как я ни старался" - это "очень старался".  А вот "откуда ни возьмись" - что это?  Как будто ниоткуда не взялся (=из воздуха), неизвестно  откуда  взялся - это варианты прямого толкования, выбор НИ следует объяснять  именно из прямого значения. А словарное значение оборота - это  "совершенно неожиданно, внезапно, точно снег на голову".

Comment: Вера, при чем тут словарное значение? Фразеологизмы (и даже отдельные слова) обладают свойством идиоматичности. Поэтому выбор "НИ" как раз и НЕ следует выводить из словарного значения оборота.

Comment: 1. Это не фразеологизм в чистом виде, во всяком случае не идиома. То, что его упоминают в словарях фразеологизмов -  ничего в этом смысле не значит.  Кого ни спроси, где ни пиши, чем ни стирай... - все фразеологизмы, что ли?

Comment: 2. Его словарное значение **вытекает ** из составляющих. А упоминают в словарях именно потому, что "вытекание" это можно понять по-разному. Вот Вы (вместе с дежурным) не хотите понять так, как я. И поэтому переспрашиваете.  А я понимаю именно так, как сказал. "откуда ни возьмись" = "и откуда только взялся", "откуда возьмись". Всё. Именно взялся. "Ни" - усилительная. остальноге от лукавого. Или от Груманта.

Comment: 3. про три слова - не понял. Почему три?

Answer (score 1):

"*откуда ни возьмись*" ~ "*откуда бы НИ взялся*", а здесь уже всё понятно.

Comment: А как "откуда бы ни взялся" связано со словарным значением "внезапно, вдруг"?

Comment: Нет, не думаю, чтобы было связано. Но это дела не меняет.

Comment: Менять-то не меняет, но нет нужной ясности. Как обозначить переход?

Comment: Честно говоря, не понимаю, что вам неясно. Фразеологизм. Его значение не есть сумма значений составляющих слов. Но происхождение его именно такое: "откуда (бы) ни взялся". *Вдруг, откуда ни взялся, Васька идёт.*

Comment: Фразеологизмы обслуживают два словаря: толковый и этимологический, они объясняют как значение, так и происхождение устойчивого выражения.

Comment: И что из этого?

Comment: Из этого следует, что не мешало бы понять, как связаны значения "откуда бы ни взялся" и "вдруг, неожиданно"? Но вы отвечаете, что никак не связаны.

Comment: Вера, а чем вам не понравилось объяснение из то же форума?

Comment: Правила правописания частиц НЕ и НИ есть в языке русском и на этот случай.
Чтобы его понять и применить, давайте закончим предложение.
Например, имеем такое: Вдруг откуда ... возьмись, в руках фокусника появился голубь.

Comment: Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточное предложение присоединяется к главной части наречием (относительным) откуда вместе с частицей.

Comment: Частица в придаточном предложении стоит перед сказуемым.
Она придает наречию обобщающий смысл, усиливая утверждение (не отрицание!), что кто-то или что-то появляется неизвестно откуда. Так говорят обычно о внезапном появлении кого-нибудь или чего-нибудь.В этом случае в сложноподчиненных предложениях для связи главных предложений с придаточными к относительным местоимениям (а также наречиям относительным) для усиления утверждающего смысла прибавляется частица НИ.

Comment: Частица ни перед сказуемым может быть только в предложениях сложных, в его придаточных частях,и в приведенном выражении как раз все перечисленные условия присутствуют.
Поэтому правильно написать ОТКУДА НИ возьмись ...

Comment: >> **Вера: Из этого следует, что не мешало бы понять, как связаны значения "откуда бы ни взялся" и "вдруг, неожиданно"?** Как это влияет на правописание? Вы же задали вопрос: *"Здесь пишется НИ. А почему?"* А теперь уже другой вопрос. Это перебор. ))

Answer (score 1):

**Откуда ни возьмись** — то есть **Ни оттуда, ни отсюда**, как будто ниоткуда.

Comment: Ниоткуда не взялся  - здесь перед глаголом  "взяться" отрицательная частица НЕ.

Comment: Мы же о том говорим, что ВЗЯЛОСЬ. Ниоткуда взялось. Другое дело, что мы будто не замечаем, что не ВЗЯЛОСЬ, а  ВОЗЬМИСЬ, т.е. повелительной формы, и к тому же не уточняем смысл: возьмись как стань-будь-появись или как схватись-ухватись-тронь.

Comment: Можно составить магическое заклинание: появись, октуда ни возмись

Answer (score 1):

Откуда-то взялся. Откуда? А ниоткуда: ни оттуда, ни отсюда... откуда ни возьмись, а взялся вдруг.

Comment: Формула "откуда ни возмись" такая же, что и в "чем ни ударь", "куда ни двинься", "кого ни вспомнишь".  А, как можно видеть, во всех этих случаях частица "ни" означает свободу выбора, а не отсутствие выбора ("ни оттуда, ни отсюда").

Comment: Ваши варианты: 1) ниоткуда, 2) неизвестно откуда,  но   они больше похожи на толкование, а что напрямую усиливает частица НИ?

Comment: "во всех этих случаях частица "ни" означает свободу выбора" - при чем тут свобода, да еще выбора? Здесь именно усиление, причем  именно глагола, а не союзного слова. А вот то, что Вы нашли образцы для этой матрицы выражений - это правильно. Видно, что не фразеологизм.

Comment: "но они больше похожи на толкование" - Vera, Это Вы в плену собственного толкования. Сознательно или нет, но вы тень на плетень наводите и других путаете. А тут все предельно ясно..

Answer (score 1):

> Взошло солнце, и снега **как не бывало**. Здесь пишется НЕ. Вдруг,
>   **откуда ни возьмись**, воробей слетел с куста. Здесь пишется НИ.

Бывает, пишут и НЕ.

Из **["Словаря синонимов и антонимов современного русского языка"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=HAaiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA254&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false)** (так же и [**здесь** -- у того же автора](https://books.google.ru/books?id=AXKkBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

==========================================================

Так же и в этих словарях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за ваше внимание к вопросу и ваши ответы.

Мое понимание выражения "откуда ни возьмись" - это тоже одна из версий, возможно, вы не согласитесь с ней.

Ближе всего мне такой ответ:  **откуда бы ни взялся предмет**, нам это неважно, мы не будем говорить или задумываться об этом. Это обычный сказочный прием, который подчеркивает отсутствие логики в происходящих событиях.